# Using UIScrollview to display .xib as different pages?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, uiscrollview

I think im missing something fundamental here because everyone seems to be able to do this simple task. Im trying to create an app that is very similar in presentation to the iPhone home screen (paging). I plan to have several pages that each have their own unique content. My understanding is that I can use UIScrollview to display and animate these pages/xib's but I have tried what seems like everything and am frustrated by the lack of instructions for newbs like me.

What I understand so far:
Declare IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller
Set options in .m or in scrollview object via IB
connect fileowner of main .xib to *scroller
connect fileowner of main .xib to delegate
then somehow call in the other xib to load as the pages for the scrollview.

One thing i have found is that most of the tutorials and source codes i get are outdated or look different. Im using xcode 4.2. ANY HELP is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie so may be I don't understand your problem exactly but if you want to represent your scroll view in pages you should enable paging for it:

```
yourCoolScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: that part I understand but how do i go about loading xib's as the pages?